# Is there way automatically test the quality of Laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel

In some PHP frameworks there exist ways to check quality of code. Laravel uses the `PSR-1` and `PSR-2` code. Is there way for checking `PSR-1` and `PSR-2`, that checks code via terminal or before commit to git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) is a useful tool for this. You can also opt in on [Scrutinizer](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/) or [StyleCI](https://styleci.io/), though they may cost money for private projects.

You could run CodeSniffer like this in a pre-commit hook:

`"vendor/bin/phpcs --extensions=php --warning-severity=0 --report=full --standard=phpcs.xml app/"` which will check for all code in the App folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHPStorm there is an option to reformat your code with PSR-2. Otherwise you can always use tools like [StyleCI](https://styleci.io).

Answer (score 1):

In 2017 you have 3 options:

- already mentioned [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/Squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)  with  PSR2, stable, but slowly evolving
- [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) with PSR2 and Symfony standards (much extra checks, closer to Laravel than PSR2)

  `vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix src --rules=@Symfony`
- or **combine the best of both above** in [EasyCodingStandard](https://github.com/Symplify/EasyCodingStandard) - super easy to use and setup